# Σ Calculation in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I am working on a financial app where I have to perform a calculation. Finance team provide me below formula for calculation as below image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But I am unable to found how to perform below operation in Swift or Objective-C.

```
     n      t-1
     Σ (1+i)
     t=1
```

Can you please help me providing an idea of the above calculation?

I also read this [link](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SigmaSwiftStatistics/3.0.1/) but not interested to use the third party.

Answer (score 2):

Swift's `reduce` function was made for this:

```
(1...n).reduce(0) { (currentResult, t) -> Decimal in
    currentResult + pow(1 + i, t - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we crack it down you have to find summation of (1 + i) ^ (t -1) where t varies from 1 to n.

Equivalent function will be

```
func evaluteSummation(n: Int, i: Int ) -> Int {
 int sum = 0
 for t in 1...n {
   sum += pow(1 + i, t - 1)
 }
 return sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do code like below.

```
func calculatePMT(targetValue : Double, interestRate : Double, time: Int) -> Double {
    let term = 1.0 + interestRate

    var denominator = 0.0

    for t in 0..<time {
        let p = pow(term, Double(t))
        denominator += p
    }

    return targetValue / denominator
}



let targetValue = 100000.0
let interestRate = 5.0
let time = 4

let pmt = calculatePMT(targetValue: targetValue, interestRate: interestRate, time: time)

print(pmt)
```